# Dagger hilt with room and job scheduler

Tags: retrofit, android-room, dagger-2, android-jobscheduler

I want to locally store data in absence of internet connection and thus am using job scheduler to schedule my syncing. So my service needs access to dao and I am not sure what the correct components needs to be defined for dagger to correctly inject dao inside my service. I do not know how to constructor inject in service either. I think it should not be constructor injected into the service. What is the proper approach? And lastly, which coroutine scope should i be using to access database from service? I also need retrofit api to make network calls. How should i inject them into my jobservice?

Comment: I recommend rewording this as a question starting with the title. Maybe "How do I access DAO?" Also, it seems like you're asking about three questions. If you can focus on one thing at a time, it's easier to answer and provides a resource for the next person facing each problem.

Comment: @TomCerul oh thanks for the suggestion.  Do you have the solution to the asked question or not?

Comment: Nope, I'm just offering feedback on how to ask so helpful people familiar with this software can answer easily.